# jQuery animation before entering the next page

Tags: jquery, animation, pageload

I'm creating a website with borders that animate out with `.click` on `#logo` to reveal the navigation at the top of the page. Once you click this again, the borders will animate back to the original state, hiding the navigation.

I have got an slight problem when I want to go to the next page.. when I click on the `#logo` to trigger the jQuery animation and then click one of the list items in the navigation to go to the next page, the state of my animated border is back to the original state when entering the page, with no animation.

I want the border to animate back, hiding the navigation, before I go to the next page for an smooth transition, but I don't know how to do this. (I'm still a beginner)

These are two screenshots of the states of the border that animates in and out:

[border state 1](http://i.imgur.com/0jyPhvj)

[border state 2](http://i.imgur.com/ZKuPQTn)

The following code works but i just don't know what to do next to achieve my goal.

Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style>
            *, *:after, *:before {
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            body, html {
                background: #f7f7f7;
                font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            /********************** Border **********************/
            /****************************************************/
            #top, #bottom, #left, #right {
                background: #00ffa3;
                opacity: 0.95;
            }

            #left, #right {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0; bottom: 0;
                width: 10px;
            }

            #left { 
                left: 0;
                z-index: 10; 
            }

            #right { 
                right: 0;
                z-index: 10; 
            }

            #top, #bottom {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0; right: 0;
                height: 10px;
                z-index: 0;
            }

            #top { 
                top: 0;
                z-index: 10; 
            }

            #bottom { 
                bottom: 0;
                z-index: 10; 
            }
            /*********** border activate & close ****************/
            /****************************************************/
            #logo {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 99;
            }
            #logo img {
                margin: 1.563em;
                width: 2.1em;
                height: 2em;
            }

            #header {
                height: 7.5em;
                z-index: 10;
            }
            /******************** navigation ********************/
            /****************************************************/

            nav {
                position: fixed;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                text-align:center;
                z-index: 99;
                width: 500px ;
                display: none;
            }

            nav li{
                display:inline;
            }
            nav ul{
                padding: 0px;
            }
            nav a { 
                display:inline-block;
                font-size: 1em;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #000;
                margin: 1.563em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

    </style>

    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $( "#logo" ).click(function() {
                    // deze gaat naar binnen.
                    if ($("#logo").hasClass("naarBinnen")) {
                        $( "#right, #left").animate({
                            width: ["7.5em","easeInOutExpo"]
                        }, 1000 );

                        $("#bottom, #top" ).animate({
                            height: ["7.5em","easeInOutExpo"]
                        }, 1000 );

                        $( "#wrapper, #wrapper2").animate({
                            width: ["80%","easeInOutExpo"],
                            height: ["70%","easeInOutExpo"]
                         }, 1000, function () {
                            $("#logo").removeClass("naarBinnen");
                            $("#logo").addClass('naarBuiten');
                         });

                        $('nav').delay(500).fadeIn('slow');

                    // deze gaat naar buiten. 
                    } else if($("#logo").hasClass("naarBuiten")) {
                        $( "#right, #left").animate({
                            width: ["10px","easeInOutExpo"]
                        }, 1000 );

                        $("#bottom, #top" ).animate({
                            height: ["10px","easeInOutExpo"]
                        }, 1000 );

                        $( "#wrapper, #wrapper2").animate({
                            width: ["90%","easeInOutExpo"],
                            height: ["85%","easeInOutExpo"]

                         }, 1000, function () {
                            $("#logo").removeClass("naarBuiten");
                            $("#logo").addClass('naarBinnen');
                         });

                        $('nav').fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                });
            })
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fullpage">
            <div id="logo" class="naarBinnen">
                <img id="logo"src="img/toggle.png">
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="section active" id="section0">
                <div id="wrapper"> 
                    <div class="main_text">
                        <p style="  text-align: center;">
                            <!--
                            Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Fusce Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. -->
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- borders --> 
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="right"></div>
            <div id="top"></div>
            <div id="bottom"></div>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: before redirect to next page, on your onclick event call animate out?

Comment: it cant be on my onclick event.. It needs to animate out when i click a list item link in my navigation before it redirects to that page

Comment: I edit my answer, is it clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the callback function of your animation method (the complete param below) :

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

When you click on the logo, if it is a `<a>` link you have to prevent the event (use : `e.preventDefault()`) to stop the redirect. Then make your animation and at the and of the animation the callback function will be called and you will manually redirect the user with a `window.location.href = url; //<- your url`

If you want more information please provide your html.

EDIT :

I see you already have a callback function. So do this :

1. Change `$( "#logo" ).click(function() {` to `$( "#logo" ).click(function(e) {`
2. In your `else{}` stop the current event by doing `e.preventDefault()` to stop the redirection
3. In your callback function make the redirection : `window.location.href = url; //<- your url`

EDIT2 : Exemple in live :

http://jsfiddle.net/b4paabuo/1/

Comment: I dont need to prevent something from happening when i click the the    #logo. The #logo is just an menu button to open and close the navigation. I just want to: click an <a> in my navigation -> border animate back -> redirect to next page,redirect to my about page for example. this doesn't work for me in some way.. or im doing it wrong.

Comment: here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BPLGRM/b4paabuo/
but it doesnt show page transitions.. so u dont see my problem.

Here is a link to all the files via dropbox so you can see:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vw4nlkt80tmaqol/breek%E2%80%A2%20website.zip

click the top left button (dots) and then portfolio.

Comment: You want to achieve something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/b4paabuo/1/ ? (try to click on your menu link).
I catch click event on <a> to do your animation then, I do what I want in the provided callback (I make an alert with the original URL for exemple).

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started ... you'll want to make use of two things,
    first prevent the default action of the click, if #logo is an a (anchor) element
       e.g. evt.preventDefault();

```
then, do all your code to add remove classes, kicking of transitions that you listed above

finally, use setInterval to do a callback after the animation finishes, to change the url  
   e.g.  return setTimeout( function(){window.location.href = 'YOUR URL' } , 1000 );
```

Comment: I just noticed Cyril answered for you ... also fine ... but if you are doing animation through your css (e.g. your class naarBuiten) and not using .animate , then the setInterval will get you the timeout you need to show the animation before going to next page.

Comment: thanks, im going to try both methods. Just to check if i can do this. This is a project to get me started with all this. ill let you know if it worked for me.